# Validator with new field in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to validate for unique value an extra field in the registration form.

Form's new field (Account):

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label for="account" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Account Name</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="account" type="text" class="form-control" name="account">

            @if ($errors->has('account'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('account') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

RegisterController:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'account'  => 'required|string|max:50|unique:accounts,name',
    ]);
}
```

validation.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify custom validation messages for attributes using the
| convention "attribute.rule" to name the lines. This makes it quick to
| specify a specific custom language line for a given attribute rule.
|
*/

'custom' => [
    'account'  => [
        'unique'   => 'Ya existe una cuenta con ese nombre. Intente nuevamente.',
        'required' => 'El campo :attribute es requerido.',
    ],
],
```

My problem is the message is not showing. It validates, the form doesn't go forward if there is an account with that name however it doesn't show the error message as it shows if the name field is empty, for example.

Thanks in advance.

Jose

Comment: make custom validation for the form request it would be easier. It's difficult to understand what's wrong.

Comment: is this ajax form submit or normal form submit?

Comment: normal, no ajax

Comment: your account filled holds number's or string?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Request:

php artisan make:request ModelRequest (in this case: UserRequest)

The syntax of this code: 'El campo :attribute es requerido.' is used in Laravel code, there are [rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules%20%22rules%7C) that Laravel gives us.

Go to your App/Http/Request folder and your new Request file will be there, open it and there is going to be 2 methods (authorize, and rules)

> public function authorize() {
>
> return true; #change to true
>
> }

```
public function rules() {

  return [
    'first_name' => 'required|unique:users'
  ];

}
```

Create another method called messages:

```
public function messages() {

  return [
    'first_name.required' => 'The Error message you want for that validation',
  ];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I store the Validator instance in a variable instead of a function outcome, so I can call the MessageBag instance in another variable, IMHO you need to change the function to

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'account'  => 'required|string|max:50|unique:accounts,name',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        // $errors is what you seek
    }

}
```

> After calling the errors method on a Validator instance, you will receive an  Illuminate\Support\MessageBag instance, which has a variety of convenient methods for working with error messages. The $errors variable that is automatically made available to all views is also an instance of the MessageBag class.

[laravel.com #working-with-error-messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#working-with-error-messages)